# Does the distance map send closed sets to closed sets?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, closed-map

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $x_0$ be an element in $X$. Define $f:X \to \mathbb R$ by $f(x)=d(x_0,x)$. Does this map send closed sets to closed sets? Further, let $C$ be a closed subset of $X$. Is $d(x_0,C) \in f(C)$?

Comment: What have you tried? Where do you get stuck?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  Let X = $\{-1\} \cup \{1/n : n \text{ a positive integer} \}$, let $C = \{ 1/n : n \text{ a positive integer } \}$,  $x_0 = -1$.

$X$ with the inherited metric is a discrete space. $C$ is a closed subset of $X$, but $f(C) = \{ 1 + 1/n : n \text{ a positive integer } \}$ isn't a closed subset of $\mathbb R$. Further, $d(-1, C) = 1 \notin f(C)$.